# TTF_GetError from SDL2_ttf returns an empty string

Tags: c, sdl-2

this is the function the problem is in

```
void Video_OpenFont(Video* video, char* path) {
    video->font = TTF_OpenFont(path, 0xFFFF);

    if (video->font == NULL) {
        FATAL("Failed to open font"); // TODO: make a window for this and reset
    }

    // generate characters
    for (uint32_t i = 1; i < ARRAY_LEN(video->characters); ++ i) {
        if (i == 173) {
            continue; // idk
        }

        SDL_Color colour      = {255, 255, 255, 255};
        char      asString[2] = {(char) i, 0};

        SDL_Surface* textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(
            video->font, asString, colour
        );

        if (textSurface == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "TTF error for character %d: %s\n", i, TTF_GetError());
            FATAL("Failed to render text");
        }

        video->characters[i] = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(
            video->renderer, textSurface
        );

        if (video->characters[i] == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "SDL error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            FATAL("Failed to create texture");
        }
    }
}
```

running it shows this

```
TTF error for character 1: 
source/sdl.c:68: Failed to render text
```

this is the Video structure

```
typedef struct Video {
    SDL_Window*   window;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer;
    TTF_Font*     font;
    SDL_Texture*  characters[256];
} Video;
```

the characters array is like a cache of textures for each character, to make rendering faster (im making a terminal emulator)

i need the error to show so i can know why it's failing to render a character

I did try making it start rendering printable characters at 33 but that failed too

Edit: more info
pretty sure this is the font im using: https://www.dafont.com/perfect-dos-vga-437.font

i also tried making it keep trying to render each character from 1 to 255, and incrementing a counter when it succeeds
it failed to render every character, still with empty error messages

Comment: i tried making it start where printable characters start in ASCII (33) but it still fails

Comment: Don't comment on your question, [edit] it. What is the numeric value `1` meant to look like in this font? Do codes outwith ASCII have visual representations?

Comment: I used this font for a previous project and it's just CP437, so 1 is a smiley face

Answer (score -1):

the problem was the ptsize parameter in TTF_OpenFont

i set it to 0xFFFF because the docs say " If the value is too high, the last indexed size will be the default."
how will i know what to pass for each font though?

edit: 300 seems high and it works fine

Comment: I don't quite understand how you're interpreting the docs here, but they're _not_ saying "pass in the highest value you can think of". You should pass in a reasonable size (in pt) for rendering, typical values for computer screens are somewhere between 8 and 48 (technically speaking pt is not a super meaningful value for screens as it's a distance measure,  whereas for screens you'd normally want to know how much space the text occupies in pixels, but it's customary to use pt regardless).